# Get list of records from mysql database having following conditions:

Tags: mysql, sql

**Firstly i apologize for vague question title, i am not sure what to write there. Please let me know and i will update it.**

Now here it goes..
    I have 3

```
Table   : target
Columns : target_id , target_employee_id, target_location_id, target_location_name, target_scheduled_on, target_exec_end_time, target_damaged, target_damaged_text


Table   : employee  
Columns : employee_id, employee_manager_id

Table   : location
Columns : location_id, location_name
```

Little Explaination-> Managers role is to create a target for employee meaning a new target will have the location name and the scheduled on. Then employee will visit that location and report if there are any damages. This can happen multiple times in a month for same location.

What i need to show-> a list of targets having damages - between two dates (target_exec_end_time) and if there are multiple records of that same location then show the one having max date.

More Explaination-> There can be multiple entries of targets having same location but i need to show only one instance. [target table image](http://tinypic.com/r/2mwil3t/6)

I have tried my best to explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check if location table column names are right?

Comment: let me edit it again. column names were changed during edit by raheel.

Comment: some ups for question will not hurt guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
 select * from target join employee on target.target_employee_id = employee.employee_id
     join location on target.target_location_name = location.location_name
     where target_exec_end_time between <start_date> and <end_date>
        and target_exec_end_time = (select max(target_exec_end_time) from location loc2
        where loc2.location_name = target.location_name)
     group by target.location_name;
```

Not sure about having both `target_exec_end_time` clauses in the where though. Maybe you just want the max value?

Comment: please give me some time to understand.

Comment: Sir, could you please explain what exactly you are doing in the query. It is giving me an error. Perhaps a little understanding might help.

Comment: Unknown column 'employee_id' in 'from clause'

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.target_location_name,case when t.target_damaged >0 
then t.target_damaged_text else 'Not Damaged' end target_damaged_text, 
max(t.target_exec_end_time) from target t
inner join employee e on t.target_employee_id=e.employee_id
inner join location l on t.target_location_id=l.location_id
where t.target_exec_end_time between 'DATE1' and 'DATE2'
group by t.target_id,t.target_damaged_text
```

Comment: Sir, i have to show target_location_name and target_damaged_text.

Comment: @dreamer did you try this?

Comment: I did, and i think there is a need of more explaination.

Comment: i have added more explaination

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(target_exec_end_time), *
FROM target
WHERE target_damaged=1
    AND target_exec_end_time BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY target_location_id
```

Comment: Here I'm assuming that, if a target is detected as damaged and later one (still within the time interval) as not damaged, you still want to see the damage. If that's not what you need, the query needs some adapting.

Comment: Please allow me to add more explaination.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM target WHERE target_damaged=1 AND target_exec_end_time BETWEEN '2012-' at line 1

Comment: Hm, not sure which part MySQL doesn't like, with SQLite it works fine.